# Having issues in filtering with product list with data attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

```
<div id="prod">
<div class="content" data-brand="Andrew" data-price="1000" data-store="JCPenny">Andrew</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-brand="Hill" data-price="1200" data-store="JCPenny">Hill</div><br />

    <div class="content" data-brand="Andrew" data-price="2000" data-store="JCPenny">Andrew</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-brand="Hill" data-price="800" data-store="SuperMart">Andrew</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-brand="Hill" data-price="1300" data-store="SuperMart">Hill</div><br />
    <div class="content" data-brand="Andrew" data-price="800" data-store="JCPenny">Hill</div><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Andrew">Andrew
    <input type="checkbox" class="brand" id="Hill">Hill
    <input type="checkbox" class="store" id="JCPenny">JCPenny
    <input type="checkbox" class="store" id="SuperMart">SuperMart
        </div>

//checkBox();
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){

    alert("check");
    var a=$("input.brand");
    var b=$("input.store");
    var brand="";
    var store="";

     

       if($(a).is(":checked")) {
           alert("brand checked");
        $('#prod >div').hide();
            brand=$(this).attr('id');
           console.log(brand+","+store);
        displaydivs(brand,store);
       }
   else{ 
       $('#prod >div').show();
       
       brand=""
        displaydivs(brand,store);
        }

});


    function displaydivs(brand,store)
    {
    if(brand!="" & store!=""){ 
        alert(brand);
        alert(store);
        $("#prod >div").hide();
         $("#prod >div[data-store="+store+"][data-brand="+brand+"]").show();

         }
         else if(brand!="" & store==""){ 
$("#prod >div").hide();
         $('#prod >div[data-brand="'+brand+'"]').show();
         }
         else if(brand=="" & store!=""){
$("#prod >div").hide();
         $("#prod >div[data-store="+store+"]").show();
         }
         }
```

I created a code regarding my div filtration. In this code, I am having data-brand and data-store as two attributes of div and I'm having checkboxes related to these divs as 'ids', 'brand' and 'store' respectively. When I'm filtering with a brand or store at one time. Like if you selected one brand or one store checkbox (either of them), it filters correctly based on selection. Let's say you selected one of the store checkboxes, then we made a second selection from the store checkbox list. We should then be able to see both the selected stores' list. In other words, both JCPenny and Supermart divs should be shown, not the earlier selected div. But when I'm selecting the second time store checkbox list, it hides the first selected checkbox related divs and displays the second or latest selected checkbox divs. A similar issue is for the Brand checkbox.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code is a mess. Your problem is that you call displaydivs twice sometimes, once for each checked input field.

Comment: K.i have removed that second if block of store .now there is only one call for displaydivs function.now also if i select two brand checkboxes from the list,its showing the results only for second one...what to change now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the JS code you need to modify:

```
    var a=$("input.brand");
    var b=$("input.store");
    var brand=new Array();
    var store=new Array();
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $('#prod >div').hide();
       if(this.className == "brand"){
           console.debug("brand checked");
           brand.push($(this).attr('id'));
        }else if(this.className == "store"){
           console.debug("store checked");
           store.push($(this).attr('id'));
        }
         console.log(brand+","+store);
         displaydivs(brand,store);
    }else{
     $('#prod >div').show();
     if(this.className == "brand"){
         var index = brand.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));
         if (index > -1) {
            brand.splice(index, 1);
         }       
     }else if(this.className == "store"){
         var index = store.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));
         if (index > -1) {
            store.splice(index, 1);
         } 
     }
     displaydivs(brand,store);
    }     
});


    function displaydivs(brand,store)
    {
        $("#prod >div").hide();
    if(brand.length > 0 & store.length > 0){ 
        $.each(brand, function( index, value ){
            var temp = $("#prod >div[data-brand="+value+"]")[0];
            var data = $(temp).attr("data-store");
            var idx = store.indexOf(data);
            if(idx > -1){
              $("#prod >div[data-brand="+value+"][data-store="+data+"]").show();
            }            
        });  
        $.each(store, function( index, value ){
            var temp = $("#prod >div[data-store="+value+"]")[0];
            var data = $(temp).attr("data-brand");
            var idx = brand.indexOf(data);
            if(idx > -1){
              $("#prod >div[data-brand="+data+"][data-store="+value+"]").show();
            }            
        });
    }
    else if(brand.length > 0 & !(store.length > 0)){ 
        $.each( brand, function( index, value ){
            $("#prod >div[data-brand="+value+"]").show();
        });
    }
    else if(!(brand.length > 0) & store.length > 0){ 
        $.each( store, function( index, value ){
            $("#prod >div[data-store="+value+"]").show();
        });
    }else{
        $("#prod >div").show();
    }
    }
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qxxL2/4/

Comment: its the same issue mam.once u click on andrew checkbox and then u click on hill with both selected,its showing only hill related checkboxes...not the andrew ones

Comment: @Dipali-mam,can u please help on the issue above issue i mentioned, i tried hard to solve it.this is the only thing left,for rest all your effort i want to say you thanks

Comment: @Dipali-Thanks for such a nice solution,can u do one small change please.Like if u select a brand checkbox out of list(Andrew or Hill).After then u get related divs visible.lets say u select Andrew,After than if u select one store (either of two).lets say u selected JCPenny,Then after that it should match the both i.e.Andrew and JCPenny,and should give those divs where Andrew and JCPenny is present.Like in this code if u are selecting JCPenny first then four divs are coming and then u select hill,then should give one div becausehill and jcpenny are together only in one div.Thanks a lot mam