# Show all divs on Unchecking the checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code for product list in different divs based on different data attributes like data-brand,data-store and some more. I am filtering the records with checkbox selection which my friend helped me to develop.I need small change in this.Look at the code.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="content" 
           data-category="shoes" 
           data-price="4000" 
           data-size="38" 
           data-brand="Nike">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80">
        <p>Nike 38<br>$4000</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content" 
           data-category="shirts" 
           data-price="6000" 
           data-size="20"
           data-brand="Nike">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x80">
        <p>Nike 20<br>$6000</p>
      </div>    
      <div class="content" 
           data-category="shoes" 
           data-price="500" 
           data-size="20"
           data-brand="Andrew">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80">
        <p>Andrew 20<br>$500</p>
      </div>  
      <div class="content" 
           data-category="shoes" 
           data-price="780" 
           data-size="42"
           data-brand="Andrew">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80">
        <p>Andrew 42<br>$780</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content" 
           data-category="shirts" 
           data-price="1200" 
           data-size="40"
           data-brand="Sunbaby">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x80">
        <p>Sunbaby 40<br>$1200</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content" 
           data-category="shoes" 
           data-price="2000" 
           data-size="70"
           data-brand="Andrew">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80">
        <p>Andrew 70<br>$2000</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content" 
           data-category="shoes" 
           data-price="800" 
           data-size="50"
           data-brand="Sunbaby">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/120x80">
        <p>Sunbaby 50<br>$800</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content" 
           data-category="shirts" 
           data-price="1300"
           data-size="20"
           data-brand="Nike">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x80">
        <p>Nike 20<br>$1300</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content" 
           data-category="shirts" 
           data-price="800" 
           data-size="35"
           data-brand="Andrew">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x80">
        <p>Andrew 35<br>$800</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form id="filter">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" 
               name="brand" 
               value="Andrew" checked>               
               Andrew
        </input>
        <input type="checkbox" 
               name="brand" 
               value="Sunbaby">
               Sunbaby
        </input>
        <input type="checkbox" 
               name="brand" 
               value="Nike">
               Nike
        </input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" 
               name="category" 
               value="shoes" checked>               
               Shoes
        </input>
        <input type="checkbox" 
               name="category" 
               value="shirts">
               Shirts
        </input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" 
               name="price" 
               value="0-9000"         
               checked>
               All
        </input>
        <input type="radio" 
               name="price" 
               value="0-999">
               $0-$1000
        </input>
        <input type="radio" 
               name="price" 
               value="1000-2000">
               $1000-$2000
        </input>
      <div> 
        <div>
        <input type="radio" 
               name="size" 
               value="0-80"         
               checked>
               All
        </input>
        <input type="radio" 
               name="size" 
               value="0-25">
               Small
        </input>
        <input type="radio" 
               name="size" 
               value="26-45">
               Medium
        </input>
        <input type="radio" 
               name="size" 
               value="46-80">
               Big
        </input>
      <div> 
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

css

```
.hidden {display: none;}

.content {border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #bbb;padding: 5px; margin: 5px; float: left;}
#filter {clear: left;}
```

script

```
var filterContentForm = function(content, form){  
  var filter = function() {  
    var checkBoxGroups = {},
        radioGroups = {};
    var addRadioGroup = function(name){
      radioGroups[name] = {      
        el: $('input[name='+name+']:checked')
      };
      var n = radioGroups[name];
      n.el
      .each(function(){
        n.range = $(this).val().split('-');
        n.from = Number(n.range[0]);
        n.to = Number(n.range[1]);      
      });
    };      
    $('#filter input[type=radio]')
    .each(function(){
      addRadioGroup($(this).attr('name'));
    });      
    var addCheckBoxGroup = function(name){
      checkBoxGroups[name] = {
        el: $('input[name='+name+']:checked'),      
        ch: []
      };
      var n = checkBoxGroups[name];
      n.el.each(function(){
        n.ch.push($(this).val());
      });
    };
    $('#filter input[type=checkbox]')
    .each(function(){
      addCheckBoxGroup($(this).attr('name'));
    });
    var contents = $(content), all = 0;
    contents.removeClass('hidden')
    .each(function(){
      var $this = $(this),
          price = $this.data('price');
      for(var c in radioGroups){ 
        var n = radioGroups[c],
            d = Number($this.data(c));
        if(d < n.from || d > n.to){
          $this.addClass('hidden');
          all++;
          return;
        }
      }    
      var show = 0, i;
      for(var c in checkBoxGroups){   
        var n = checkBoxGroups[c], 
            d = $this.data(c);      
        for(i = 0; i < n.ch.length; i++){        
          if(d === n.ch[i]) {
            show++; break;
          }
        } 
      }
      var l = Object.keys(checkBoxGroups).length;
      if(show < l) {
        $this.addClass('hidden');
        all++;
      }
    });
    if(all > contents.length - 1) 
      contents.removeClass('hidden');
  };
  $(form+' input').change(filter);
  filter();
};
filterContentForm('.content', '#filter'); 
#filter {clear: left;}
```

The above code is working fine.I just need one small change in this. That is, on start two checkboxes are checked i.e.for brand i.e.Nike and category i.e. shoes. I just want that on the start, these two checkboxes also need to be unchecked,all records visible,but when I am removing the 'checked' from Andrew and Shoes checkbox,Filtering doesnot happen.

Just guide me how to keep all checkboxes unchecked on start and then filtering should work after selecting the checkboxes.
Thanks for help

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle of this

Comment: @NevilleNazerane http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/AgUQT/

Comment: try to get help from my previous answer :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22759872/1982680

Comment: _how to keep all checkboxes unchecked on start_ ? Just delete checked property from checkboxes.

Comment: I don't think your filter function works properly but this is how to start with nothing checked and then attach your function to the checkbox / radio change http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/AgUQT/2/

Comment: @DipaliVasani-I tried correcting the code from your example.but i m unable to make it work..can u please help in correcting it....

Comment: @Pete-Can u please correct the code as i m not good in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Your filter code seems to be a little buggy.
Make sure you are adding the jquery js in the header!

To toggle checked/unchecked state of your checkboxes and/or radio-buttons simply add/remove the checked attribute from the tag

```
<input type="checkbox" 
           name="category" 
           value="shoes" **checked**>
```

Comment: @Varun-When i am trying with your logic i.e. putting **checked** with shoes checkbox only.filter works.But when i keep **checked** with both shoes and andrew checkbox.filter doesnot work.How to make the filter work keeping all checkboxes unchecked....

Comment: Just checked it on the jsfiddle link given in the comment above by Anton. That combination is working fine. The problem occurs when either on of the "brands" or "category" are not at all checked.

Comment: I checked in that one only.can u please check that once

Comment: I will update you with the exact problem once i get time to investigate. May be in another couple of hours!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is the problem:

You are checking the following condition

> `if(show < l)`

where `show` is the count of filterCategories [ in your case: **brand and category**] that are checked. This is being compared against `l` which is count of total filterCategories present.

So, when only one of the categories is checked, this conditions becomes true, and following code

> ```
>    `$this.addClass('hidden');
>     all++;`
> ```

gets executed. This makes your `all++` reach the value of `contents.length` hence your following code gets executed

> ```
>   if(all > contents.length - 1) 
>   contents.removeClass('hidden');
> ```

which overrides the filters and shows all the items [ in your case the divs ]

To fix this see the following code. The `activeFilterCount` variable is the change that is required. Just replace your code from `var show=0,i;` to `all++;}` with the following code:

> `var show = 0, i, activeFilterCount=0;
>                 for(var c in checkBoxGroups){
>                   var n = checkBoxGroups[c], 
>                       d = $this.data(c);
>                   if(n.ch.length > 0){
>                       activeFilterCount++;
>                   }
>                   for(i = 0; i < n.ch.length; i++){
>
>                     if(d === n.ch[i]) {
>                       show++; break;
>                     }
>                   } 
>                 }
>                 if(show < activeFilterCount) {
>                   $this.addClass('hidden');
>                   all++;
>                 }`

I know it got a little too lengthy, but I hope it helps you! Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: @Varun-seems like code is not working on my local pc.but working on fiddle.any clues sir????

Comment: Well its difficult to even guess without looking at the files. Can you elaborate what is not working? One issue could be caching. clear your cache and try.